# Нужен js скрипт, который будет загружать другой скрипт после определенного события

Tags: javascript, html, material-design

К сожалению, моих навыков js недостаточно, чтобы сделать это самому. Краткая суть проблемы:
Есть фреймворк MDL. Он перестраивает страницу после загрузки так, что не работают некоторые скрипты или срабатывают повторно.
Вот подобная проблема: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1926
Там же и её решение.

Как я понял нужен скрипт, который выполнит какой-либо код после срабатывания события *mdl-componentupgraded*

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь

Написал такой код, но он не работает:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("mdl-componentupgraded", displayDate);

function displayDate() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
}
</script>
```

Нужно, динамически загрузить код в элемент, если на нём срабатывает mdl-componentupgraded

Comment: Как именно "он не работает"? Не вызывается `displayDate()`? Появляются ошибки?

Comment: можете добавить [краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) например на jsfiddle, в котором воспроизводится ваша проблема?